# Data structure that supports access via index as well as key

Tags: c#, data-structures, dictionary, indexing, key

Dictionary supports access of elements via a key.
List supports access via index.
Is there any data structure that supports access via both key and index?

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
d.Add("abc", "def");
d.Add("ghi", "ghi");
d.Add("abcd", "abcd");
d.Add("how", "howis");
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in d)
   Console.WriteLine(kv.Key);
```

**Output is**

```
abc
ghi 
abcd 
how
```

So the items come out in the same sequence as they were added. Does that mean dictionary maintains items sequentially ? If yes, can we access them by index ? If no, is there any such collection available which supports accessing elements by index as well as key ?

Comment: Order of elements in Dictionary is undefined, you shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 5):

I think [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx)  <strike>or [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx)</strike>   is what you are looking for.

Comment: OrderedDictionary takes both key and value as string. Do we have a generic version available ?

Comment: Please read the doc. OrderedDictionary takes object for key as well as value.

Comment: Still a generic version would be better. :-)

Comment: I don't think so; you could, I think, roll your own fairly easily by making a class implement `IList<>` and `IDictionary<,>` by having a `List<TKey>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` inside it. (Consider, though, what happens if `TKey` is `int`: both indexes will be by `int`; you'll probably also want `GetByKey(..)` and `GetByIndex(..)` methods to clarify when needed.

Comment: ...or by wrapping a private `OrderedDictionary` in generics.

Answer (score 1):

Values in a dictionary are not necessarily unique, hence the key lookup.

The order of elements in a dictionary is non-deterministic, hence the [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx).

Comment: If the order of elements in dictionary is non-deterministic, how does for-each/Enumerator gets them in the sequence they were added ?